# Setting section counter arbitrarily

Tags: counters

I am writing a tex file of homework problems and the counter in the code below starts from $1$. How can I set the counter to start from $5$?

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\newcommand{\homeworkProblemName}{}%
\newcounter{homeworkProblemCounter}%
\newenvironment{homeworkProblem}[1][Problem     \arabic{homeworkProblemCounter}]%
{\stepcounter{homeworkProblemCounter}%
\renewcommand{\homeworkProblemName}{#1}%
\section{\homeworkProblemName}%
\enterProblemHeader{\homeworkProblemName}}%
{\exitProblemHeader{\homeworkProblemName}}%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\setcounter{homeworkProblemCounter}{4}
```

Comment: In which line do I put this piece of code?

Comment: @failexam Right after `\newcounter{homeworkProblemCounter}`

Comment: @siracusa Or anywhere after that before you first use the environment, in fact.

Comment: @failexam After the new counter is created and before you use the environment. Right after making the counter is a good place as siracusa suggests.